# How to customise Activities logged at Contact Notes in Salesforce to appear under Account past activities and vice versa

Tags: activities, activityhistory

**Account has lookup relationship with Contact Notes. 
The requirement is notes/tasks logged at Contact Notes to appear under Account activities section (past activities) and vice versa.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity History pseudo-related list is built-in functionality. You cannot customize it to display Custom Object records or Activity History records linked to related objects.

Activities roll up natively to their `WhoId` and `WhatId` relations, as well as to their `AccountId`, a relationship that is [calculated by the system](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194177&type=1) based on the `WhoId` and `WhatId`. You can't change this behavior other than by the limited options available in activity settings; in particular, you cannot change it to incorporate your custom objects as an additional roll-up relationship.

Your only option for thoroughgoing customization is to build a custom UI component that generates the combined view you desire.

Comment: Agree David, cant we achieve this behavior through trigger on Task object and clone the record with WhatId?

Comment: @PramodSingh Probably, yes, but then you'll have multiple copies of the same Task record taking up data storage and which you would have to maintain in sync with one another - no small effort.